# How to use register from react-hook-forms with Headless UI Combobox

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, headless-ui

I have this piece of code where I am trying to wire up the [Combobox Component](https://headlessui.com/react/combobox) from [Headless UI](https://headlessui.com/) with react-hook-form. Whenever I try to enter a different value and select a different option it gives me an error saying -
`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')`

I have tried a lot of different variations but I fail to use the `Combobox` with `register`. Any help would be appreciated. I want to use `register` to make this work and don't want to use the other `Controller` method of doing ways from `react-hook-form`.

```
import React from "react";

import { useState } from "react";
import { Combobox } from "@headlessui/react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

const people = [
  { id: 1, name: "Durward Reynolds" },
  { id: 2, name: "Kenton Towne" },
  { id: 3, name: "Therese Wunsch" },
  { id: 4, name: "Benedict Kessler" },
  { id: 5, name: "Katelyn Rohan" },
];

function Example() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

  const filteredPeople =
    query === ""
      ? people
      : people.filter((person) => {
          return person.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase());
        });

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    setValue,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();

  const submit = (data) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)}>
      <Combobox
        as="div"
        name="assignee"
        defaultValue={people[0]}
        {...register("assignee")}
      >
        <Combobox.Input
          onChange={(event) => setQuery(event.target.value)}
          displayValue={(person) => person.name}
        />
        <Combobox.Options>
          {filteredPeople.map((person) => (
            <Combobox.Option key={person.id} value={person}>
              {person.name}
            </Combobox.Option>
          ))}
        </Combobox.Options>
      </Combobox>
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default function check() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Example />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely not a good idea to attach `react-hook-form` handlers to the `Combobox` directly.

1. `Input > onChange` will give you an event with a string `target.value`, not a `Location / User / ...` model from the API. Will you do a copy request to "unpack" it in `handleSubmit`? And, if so, – how are you going to handle an API error *there*?!

2. The input might be associated with an API error at the `Combobox` level. You'll have to be extra careful to distinguish "successful" and "failed" strings at the form component level.
3. The string might be non-parsable at the form component level. Especially with "multiple" mode, where you can render an aggregate info, like "3 items are selected" in the input. And THAT will be your value if you expand `register` to the `Combobox.Input`.
4. Finally, in some other (non HeadlessUI) `Combobox` implementations, the value will preserve raw user input.

For example:

1. user inputs: "United"
2. select suggests: "United States", "United Kingdom", ...
3. user selects some option
4. `Combobox` takes a new value but the `Combobox.Input` value still holds "United"

You probably want to stick to a portable and future-proof approach.

---

The conclusion is the same: let `Combobox` parse and translate values for you. Provide `onChange` to `Combobox`, not `Combobox.Input`. But that is possible only with *controlled* RHF API variant.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to use `Combobox` without `Controller`:

The problem is that `Combobox` calls `onChange` with bare `value` but RHF's `onChange` handler returned by `register` expects an `event` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was through using `useController` hook. (I assumed OP is skeptical about using `<Controller>` component, not the `useController` hook + I was not able to do this using `register` either)

First you need `control` from `useForm`:

```
 const {
    control,
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<DataSchema>()
```

Then you need `field` from `useController` hook:

```
// name is the name of your component used by react hook form
const { field } = useController({ control, name });
```

And now the trick is that you pass `value` and `onChange` from `field` to `<Combobox>` component and `onBlur`, `name` and/or `ref` to `<Combobox.Input>`:

```
<Combobox value={field.value} onChange={field.onChange} by="id">
  <Combobox.Input
    onBlur={field.onBlur}
    name={field.name}
    ref={field.ref}
    // you can still handle onChange however you want, 
    // as this input value is used to filter combobox options
    onChange={(e) => setFilter(e.target.value)}
  />
</Combobox>
```

You can find out what each of `field` properties does on `react-hook-form` site  [here](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/usecontroller) under `Tips`

If your `combobox` component is a child of a component where you use `useForm`, and you're using typescript, you can define types for `control` and `name` as props like this:

```
type Props<TFormValues extends FieldValues> = {
  control: Control<TFormValues>;
  name: Path<TFormValues>;
  // other props
};

export default function MyCombobox<TFormValues extends FieldValues>({
  control,
  name,
  // other props
}: Props<TFormValues>) {
  // component
};
```

And if you need to pass `field` down to the child component:

```
type Props<TFormValues extends FieldValues> = {
  field: ControllerRenderProps<TFormValues, Path<TFormValues>>;
  // other props
};

export default function MyInput<TFormValues extends FieldValues>({
  field,
  // other props
}: Props<TFormValues>) {
  //component
};
```

Answer (score -2):

```
const { register } = useFormContext();

<Combobox.Input
    {...register(id)}
    id={id}
    onChange={(event) => setQuery(event.target.value)}
/>
```